# PHP - composer autoloader cause html to show in browser

Tags: javascript, php, html, composer-php

I have a PHP html script which load the autoloaded libraries from composer:

```
<?php
require_once "vendor/autoload.php";
?>

<html>
    <body>
        Test
    </body>
</html>
```

When i'm browsing to this file using Chrome - I see nothing (the file is in Apache's /var/www folder)

When i'm running CLI `php index.php` I get the following output:

```
<html>
    <body>
        Test
    </body>
</html>
```

When i'm commenting out the `require_once` line - I see the html in the browser.

This make me things that something in the libraries i'm loading is breaking the code.

I can't understand why I see the full page in CLI and not in the browser...

What can cause that?

Comment: You change the line where you load the autoloader to `require __DIR__."/vendor/autoload.php";` as the web server process may have issues choosing the right file to include when using relative paths.

Comment: Also, turn on error reporting in your development environment to see the actual error message instead of a white page.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.
i look in the Apache logs and fount that the memory_limit is to low. I changed the memory_limit from 128mb to 536870912 and it solved the problem

Comment: O_O You need more than 128MB just to load the autoloader...!?

Comment: 536870912mb? The F... O_o. You may want to look into the autoloader FYI. It *will* cause more issues if it requires more than 128mb